How to handle offers of auto-transferring a paper to another journal following a desk rejection?
Following a desk rejection of a paper submitted to one of the Springer journals, the editorial submission advisor sent me a recommendation of other suitable journals, with an offer to automatically submit the paper in my stead. I politely declined, noting that I intend to revise my paper sufficiently before submitting it again independently. The submission advisor, however, replied again, pointing out that letting her transfer my paper will save me some time, while also allowing me to make any revisions before continuing with the process. I was told that in doing so, I would also be receiving the "benefits of the transfer service", though I am not quite sure what this means.
I'd like to avoid a faux pas and would appreciate any input regarding the following.

Is it rude if I would insist on submitting independently, even if I submit to another Springer journal? I will actually use the service to auto-transfer -- see next point -- I'm just wondering what if I didn't.
I intend to submit to one of the other Springer journals, but one not on the list of the recommended ones, and one that has a higher impact factor than the first one. Is this a bad idea, signalling some unawareness that if my paper were deemed sufficiently good, higher impact journals would be included in the list?
What happens if my paper is rejected again; will the same submission advisor offer me help to re-submit elsewhere? I would feel like a dolt going through a series of rejections with the same advisor witnessing my failures.
If my paper is rejected again, I may first submit it to one of the non-Springer journals. If rejected there again, I would return to the list of proposed Springer journals. I don't believe this should be problematic, but should I watch out for something?


Is the "submission advisor" a researcher in your field (presumably on the editorial board), or a Springer employee? In either case you want to be polite, and it's perfectly fine to say no -- but it's only in the former case that I'd seriously consider the suggestion.

@academic she's a Springer employee and not a researcher as far as I can tell.

This process saves some time for the journal, for example certain initial checks they make on a newly submitted paper.  But if you intend to change the paper, or if you intend not to submit next to a Springer journal, of course you should decline.

Rejections happen to everyone but a desk rejection is often a sign that you submitted to a journal that is not suitable to your paper. If that happens frequently to you, you should put more effort into finding journals where you paper would actually be a good fit.

Of course there is no risk of misunderstanding, but, in case it was not just a typo, you may want to know that the phrase is "faux pas" (a false step, I think etymologically related to, but not the same as, a false pass).

@LSpice I stand corrected, thanks.

You are probably overthinking this. Springer likely has the same editorial management system configured for every journal, i.e., every journal has its own submission system. These journals don't directly communicate with each other - the new journal probably cannot tell that your paper was rejected by another journal, unless they explicitly search for it (or if you agree with the transfer, since in that case they get a notification). It is possible the same employee is assigned to both journals, but for a large publisher this is not probable, and even if it is the case the employee is not supposed to make academic decisions like whether to reject your paper.
From the perspective of the publisher, offering a transfer 1) helps keep the paper within the publisher's stable, which is generally a good thing; and 2) simplifies matters for the authors, since they only need to submit once. Compare e.g. graduate admissions - if you could write only one application total (as opposed to one per program), everyone would do it.
With that in mind:

Is it rude if I would insist on submitting independently, even if I submit to another Springer journal? I will actually use the service to auto-transfer -- see next point -- I'm just wondering what if I didn't.

No. The other journal likely won't know, and even if they did, they're more likely to think there's some change to the paper and/or metadata that you wanted to make.

I intend to submit to one of the other Springer journals, but one not on the list of the recommended ones, and one that has a higher impact factor than the first one. Is this a bad idea, signalling some unawareness that if my paper were deemed sufficiently good, higher impact journals would be included in the list?

No. The other journal likely won't know. Besides, there is a good chance the list of recommended journals is (largely) autogenerated, and/or there are so many possible journals that they have truncated the list.

What happens if my paper is rejected again; will the same submission advisor offer me help to re-submit elsewhere? I would feel like a dolt going through a series of rejections with the same advisor witnessing my failures.

It's quite possible they will offer to redirect to another journal again, for the reason in the second paragraph of this answer.

If my paper is rejected again, I may first submit it to one of the non-Springer journals. If rejected there again, I would return to the list of proposed Springer journals. I don't believe this should be problematic, but should I watch out for something?

Not really, except your paper would be in "limbo" while it moves between journals. Since peer review can take a long time, make sure rapid publication is not important to you.

Don't worry about "rudeness" as long as you are polite. The paper is yours and a publisher benefits from publishing it, given sufficient quality.
But, your alternate scheme seems sub-optimal in two dimensions. First, it is riskier, since a referral from an editor will hold some weight with "sister" journals. I'm guessing that the desk rejection was more a matter of journal scope than paper quality. Those other journals are likely a closer "fit" for your paper.
Second, your alternate scheme will take time, with no guarantee of success. Each independent journal you submit to will have its own procedures, all of which take time; years in some cases, depending on field and such.
You have to judge whether those two factors outweigh any perceived benefit from submitting to a higher "heat index" journal. My guess would be no, but it is yours that matters.

Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it. To be clear (I edited my post slightly), I actually intend to use the transfer service offered, given that my next choice is a journal of the same publisher. However, the journal is even slightly more selective than the first one - would you deem this a risky scheme of the "big no" category?

Not so much if it is one that the first editor will recommend. As I noted, I think it is scope more than quality. I could be mistaken, of course. It could even be backlog at the first journal.

I would add that there is no need to see a rejection by a journal as a failure. It happens all the time also to good quality manuscripts, for all kinds of reasons. Of course you want to avoid wasting time, but if you are convinced (for good reasons) you want to aim for higher impact than suggested by the editor, this is the right decision, even if the manuscript will be rejected again.

Some good answers were posted already, I would just like to add that in my experience the time-saving factor is vastly overestimated by the journals. I once went with the transfer option for an Elsevier journal and in the end not only did I have to pretty much fill out all the forms like for an original submission, but I even had to adjust the cover letter and create some additional documents that the referred-to journal asks for.
So I found zero benefit in the tranferral, I could just have submitted there on my own.

Actually the "time factor" refers to the expected time between submission and publication (assuming acceptance). It is not the effort required to submit.

I see, but that cannot be much different anyway for a desk rejection. The most time-consuming part is of course the peer-review and that will not change with a transfer. The only exception to that would be when some reviews have been conducted that are not quite positive enough for the desired journal. Then I could see how a different journal would accept the submission with fewer or even no additional reviews, but this is not the situation in this question.

@Buffy indeed. But in all likelihood, while the publication date would probably be sooner, the transferal system would increase the time between publication and submission. Because the submission date would be before OP's revisions, which in OP's scheme would not count towards the time from submission to publication. I know even of (letter) journals that have adopted a policy of rejecting papers that need major revisions with the strong suggestion to resubmit. This has the advantage for the journal that their rejection rate is increased and their publication time is (artificially) decreased.
